# Linux Bridge Network with Static IP Addresses and Firewall

Tags: debian, networking, firewall

any and all help is appreciated.
I am trying to set up my [Network Map](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47822189/ebox%20network%20map.jpg) Can you give me advice in setting up my interface file? If I set a static IP on my PLC on the same gateway, I shouldn't need to set it also in interfaces right? Setting a static IP address for eth5,6 does not allow it to get internet from eth4 (br0) for some reason. Is my firewall set up right? Because I can still see MAC addresses on my network (eth4) from eth5 and eth6. I want Panel 1-4 to have its own network.

My /etc/network/interfaces

```
# Bridge and Switch

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# eth4 to eth6 network switch
allow-hotplug eth4
iface eth4 inet manual
    pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
    pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down
allow-hotplug eth5
iface eth5 inet manual
    pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
    pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down
allow-hotplug eth6
iface eth6 inet manual
    pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
    pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down

# Setup IP address of bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth4 eth5 eth6

#######################################################################
# Bridge Firewall
# eth1 is the connection from the customer

# allows connection tracking support, needed
modprobe ip_conntrack
modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp

# enables connection tracking, needed
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# allows all outbound traffic
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth4 --out-interface eth5 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth4 --out-interface eth6 -j ACCEPT

# disallow inbound traffic
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth5 --out-interface eth4 -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth6 --out-interface eth4 -j REJECT
```

Comment: I think I want to use a virtual interface with a different metric